# Batch - Replace number after text

Tags: file, batch-file, increment

I have a problem, in a file i have this:

```
plot1:
    8 lines of content
plot2:
    8 lines of content
plot3:
    8 lines of content
plot4:
    8 lines of content
plot5:
    8 lines of content
plot6:
    8 lines of content
plot7:
    8 lines of content
plot8:
    8 lines of content
plot9:
    8 lines of content
plot10:
    8 lines of content
plot11:
    8 lines of content
plot12:
    8 lines of content
plot13:
    8 lines of content
plot14:
    8 lines of content
plot15:
    8 lines of content
plot16:
    8 lines of content
plot17:
    8 lines of content
plot18:
    8 lines of content
plot19:
    8 lines of content
plot20:
    8 lines of content
plot21:
    8 lines of content
plot22:
    8 lines of content
plot23:
    8 lines of content
plot24:
    8 lines of content
plot25:
    8 lines of content
plot26:
    8 lines of content
plot27:
    8 lines of content
plot28:
    8 lines of content
plot29:
    8 lines of content
```

And I want to be able to choose a number to replace number 1 that comes next to the word plot and increment till the end. So for example replace 1 with 60 and get plot60 till plot89.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off 
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion 

    (for /f "delims=" %%a in (file.txt
    ) do for /f "tokens=2 delims=1234567890 " %%b in ("%%~a"
    ) do if not "%%b"==":"  (
        echo(%%~a
    ) else for /f "tokens=1 delims=plot:" %%c in ("%%~a"
    ) do (
        set /a "n=%%c+59"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        echo(plot!n!:
        endlocal
    )) > out.txt
```